# Adding Async Task to JSON Crashes Activity

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, android-activity, task

I'd like to know how to add an AsyncTask (successfully) to the following code. I've already implemented the AsyncTask (to the best of my knowledge - using info I've found on the net) however it keeps crashing and I'm not sure exactly why... any help is greatly appreciated!

JAVA:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.nfc.linked.DatabaseHandler;
import com.nfc.linked.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    private class RegisterActivity extends AsyncTask<string, jsonobject="" string,=""> {
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(linkingmanager.comze.com) {

        }
    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
03-16 21:55:23.746: D/AndroidRuntime(483): Shutting down VM
03-16 21:55:23.746: W/dalvikvm(483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41604930)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  The nested type RegisterActivity cannot hide an enclosing type
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Illegal modifier for the local class RegisterActivity; only abstract or final is permitted
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error on token """", { expected
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error on token "=", delete this token
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  The method doInBackground() of type RegisterActivity must override or implement a supertype method
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.nfc.linked.RegisterActivity.<init>(RegisterActivity.java:34)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-16 21:55:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 21:55:26.296: I/Process(483): Sending signal. PID: 483 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I think you may have to reinstall eclipse or the ADT plugin. It's allowing you to run with so many compilation errors, just look at the stack trace).

Comment: It's not allowing me to run - I'm deleting the errors before running it just to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Eclipse and ADT are functioning fine : )

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix these compilation errors that are the source of this issue? I really have no idea where to start...

Comment: `onCreate()` is missing its closing brace, classes always start with Capital letters so the `AsyncTask` parameterization needs to be fixed. You also don't assign anything there (so take out the `= ""`). Is Eclipse not highlighting any of this in red?

Comment: I updated my source as you instructed - however it's still force closing. : ( 


https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rU7IvF9AkaVAutYzrqeUc4TA3EDR1BzqS1y255uv4E8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: But that's my point, you *are* running your app, but it is crashing due to the syntax errors. If Eclipse doesn't highlight any of these errors in red, i suggest you reinstall or reconfigure. 99% of the time, you should not be able to upload an apk as broken as this to your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being blunt.  You have a basic misunderstanding of Java syntax, and certainly of threading.  Somebody might take it upon themselves to reformat your code to "work", but I think you're going to be stuck in Painville for a long time without hitting the books.

No code is actually in the "doInBackground" method.  Also, the argument is not valid.  I would go on, but seriously, you need basic Java coding skills before attempting Android code.  Same as any platform (need the basic coding skills first).

Comment: I could really use some help... even if I get stuck in painville. (I'm behind on a deadline)

Comment: @user2161499 no one can help you if you don't help yourself with the basics.

Comment: I have a basic understanding - I'm just trying to follow a tutorial on creating a registration screen but when I import the code as is from the tutorial - I get force close issues.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

Take `RegisterActivity` out of `onCreate()`.

For more info you can reference [this guide.](http://www.9android.net/how-to-parsing-android-json/)